# Pandas where multiple conditions are met ; concatenate the result to create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a code below and you can see I am using `np.select` to identify if the string in my column contains any of the codes and create a reference column with the description based on the logic.

```
# Creating Score column
col         = 'codes_desc'
conditions  = [(df_merged[col].str.contains('R27', case=False)),
               (df_merged[col].str.contains('R38', case=False)),
               (df_merged[col].str.contains('R52', case=False)),
               (df_merged[col].str.contains('R62', case=False)),
               (df_merged[col].str.contains('R21', case=False)),
               (df_merged[col].str.contains('R22', case=False)),
               (df_merged[col].str.contains('R23', case=False)),
               (df_merged[col].str.contains('R57', case=False)),
               (df_merged[col].str.contains('R82', case=False)),
               (df_merged[col].str.contains('R86', case=False)),
               (df_merged[col].str.contains('R20', case=False)), 
               (df_merged[col].str.contains('R98', case=False)) 
              ]

choices     = [ 
 'The person is a Ninja',
 'The person is a Pirate',
 'The person is a Doctor',
 'The person is a Samurai',
 'The person is a Admiral',
 'The person is a Police',
 'The person is a Teacher',
 'The person is a Singer',
 'The person is a Guitarist',
 'The person is a Chef',
 'The person is a Runner',
 'The person is a Wizard'
]
df_merged["reference"] = np.select(conditions, choices, default= 'Reason Unknown')
```

But I find cases in my dataframe where the the column 'codes_desc' contains two codes for example :

```
codes_desc

The selected codes are R27, R22.
```

In this case I want my output to be like in the column 'Reference" :

```
1. 'The person is a Ninja'
2. 'The person is a Police'
```

But since `np.select` works like a case statement ; it picks up the last code description , so how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Setup

```
print(df)
   codes_desc
0  fo bar R20
1   R98 grok 
2    R98, R21
3         R82
```

#### Solution

Lets `extract` all the matching codes then `map` the `codes` to the corresponding values using a mapping dictionary then `groupby` and aggregate using `join`

```
d = {'R27': 'The person is a Ninja',
     'R38': 'The person is a Pirate',
     'R52': 'The person is a Doctor',
     'R62': 'The person is a Samurai',
     'R21': 'The person is a Admiral',
     'R22': 'The person is a Police',
     'R23': 'The person is a Teacher',
     'R57': 'The person is a Singer',
     'R82': 'The person is a Guitarist',
     'R86': 'The person is a Chef',
     'R20': 'The person is a Runner',
     'R98': 'The person is a Wizard'}


pat = r'\b(%s)\b' % '|'.join(d)
codes = df['codes_desc'].str.extractall(pat)[0]
df['reference'] = codes.map(d).groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
```

#### Result

```
   codes_desc                                        reference
0  fo bar R20                           The person is a Runner
1   R98 grok                            The person is a Wizard
2    R98, R21  The person is a Wizard, The person is a Admiral
3         R82                        The person is a Guitarist
```

Comment: Hi @Shubam, thanks for the response ; there is a problem with the first multi-index it's resetting itself to 0 in the variable ```codes``` , therefore the ```.groupby(level=0)``` is giving wrong output

Comment: @Ash Can you share the output of the code?